# Android: Dynamicly add OnClickListeners to Buttons

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

In my Activity, I look into a SQLite database (_id, name, number) and add as many buttons as I have rows in the database. For each button I dynamicly create onClickListener that will start another activity into which I need to pass data from the coresponding database row. My code follows:

```
db.open();
String name;
String number;
Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
c.moveToFirst();
int count = db.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
    name = c.getString(1);
    number = c.getString(2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(This_class.this, Other_class.class);
          intent.putExtra("name_bundle", name);
          intent.putExtra("number_bundle", number);
          startActivity(intent);
       }
    });
c.moveToNext();
}
db.close();
```

In the new Activity started by the ImageButton I work with the passed on data like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
name = extras.getString("name_bundle");
number = extras.getString("number_bundle");
```

All the buttons are created correctly, but my problem is that all of them pass on the same information. My intention was that when third button is clicked, data (columns 1 and 2 in the code) from the third row in the database are passed (In the newly started Activity I display them in a TextView). But what happens is that all the buttons pass on the same data! Data from the last row of the database to be precise. When I tried to add yet another row to the database, one extra button was created and all of them again displayed the same data from the newly created (therefore the last) row of the database. I suspect either a dum mistake in my code or completly bad approach. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: create intent before onClickListener implementation then use `button.setTag(intent);` made ONE(fx.: as class field)  OnClickListener implementation for all buttons: `static final OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
          startActivity((Intent)v.getTag());
       }` then set it to button `button.setOnClickListener(listener);`

Comment: anyway ... you're re-inveting ListView

Comment: ... you can also try to put `name` and `number` declaration **IN** `for` loop scope(by scope i mean "{}" or fist expresion) and make em final there ...

Comment: I dont realy understand what this code does but it totaly works :) I used the first approach you posted, this realy helps, thanks!!!! :)

Comment: Hint: View v is button that was clicked since Button is subclass of View ... Simply you put intent as view's tag and recover it in onClick ....

Answer (score -1):

In your new Activity use `removeExtra()`

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
name = extras.getString("name_bundle");
number = extras.getString("number_bundle");
getIntent().removeExtra("name_bundle");
getIntent().removeExtra("number_bundle");
```

When you start activity old extras are **not** replaced by new.

Comment: I added those two lines but it didnt solve the problem. Still I get only data from the last row. But the strange thing is that when the old extras are not replaced, why am I only seeing the last row data? I should be seeing only the first row data since the first button was assigned its listener as first, right?

Comment: heh ... you both should read about local vars in anonymous interface implementation `String name;
String number;` are locals ... and after last iteration of "cursor row" has some values ... then this(last) values is used in all anonymous interface implementation of OnClickListener

Comment: yeah, i think i see it. Since the listener method is called only when the button is clicked, it uses the variables i gave it, but those are already set to values from the last database row. Changing the values in this loop is totaly pointless...do you have any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: it's a matter of local var scopes ... see my comments under your question

Comment: maybe assigning IDs with button.setId (button0,1,...) to every button and when the button is clicked, parse the number from the ID and use the data from database according to the number?

Comment: @Selvin, thanks, I didn't know it. However, he still need to use `removeExtra`